# XML Encoding error while writing it in to file

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding

I think I am following the right approach but I am still getting an encoding error:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import codecs

doc = Document()
wml = doc.createElement("wml")
doc.appendChild(wml)

property = doc.createElement("property")
wml.appendChild(property)

descriptionNode = doc.createElement("description")
property.appendChild(descriptionNode)
descriptionText = doc.createTextNode(description.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
descriptionNode.appendChild(descriptionText)

file = codecs.open('contentFinal.xml', 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
file.write(doc.toprettyxml())
file.close()
```

The description node contains some characters in `ISO-8859-1 encoding`, this is encoding specified by the site it self in meta tag. But when `doc.toprettyxml()` starts writing in file I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 467, in <module>
    file.write(doc.toprettyxml())
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 60, in toprettyxml
    return writer.getvalue()
File "C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.py", line 271, in getvalue
    self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why am I getting this error as I am decoding and encoding with same standard?

**Edited**

I have following deceleration in my script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

may be this is conflicting?

Comment: I don't think the Python declaration is the problem.  Can you post the content of description, maybe?

Comment: Lets say if we have this word `Orientación` in content we got error. The site is in `espanol language`. Don't know about content as it fails before writing it in to file. If i do not use encoding at all then it writes in to file but that is not accepted by browser and they keep saying `error on line blah on column blah`

Comment: Sounds like your `description` object is a byte-string not a character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have found a solution. When ever data is in other foriegn language you just need to defined the proper encoding in xml header. You do not need to describe encoding in `file.write(doc.toprettyxml(encoding='ISO-8859-1'))` not even when you are opening a file for writing `file = codecs.open('contentFinal.xml', 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1')`. Below is the technique which i used. May be This is not a professional method but that works for me.

```
file = codecs.open('abc.xml', 'w')
xm = doc.toprettyxml()
xm = xm.replace('<?xml version="1.0" ?>', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>')
file.write(xm)
file.close()
```

May be there is a method to set default encoding in header but i could not find it.
Above method does not bring any error on browser and all data display perfectly.